How can I build a window setup file of python app?
I recently made an app using python, and want to build a setup file of it.
And most of all, I want to add a setup option that makes app run when window is booted.
I have some experiences of using pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe, but could not found any option related.
Please tell me what I should do for my objective and thank you very much.

Check in Python tutorial "argparse" .
